# How do I make my business hours appear on weekends?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using the premium scheduler plugin, and have my resources created with business hours set up with the following implementation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/businessHours-per-resource

This works fine, and I am only displaying one day at a time, so I have not included the `daysOfWeek` attribute within the object.

My issue is that when I am on a day that is a Saturday or Sunday, the business hours do not render. The entire day is greyed out as if the resource is unavailable that day, which in my case is not true.

Is there some attribute I am missing on the calendar model? Something like `showBusinessHoursOnWeekends: true`?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you didn't include the `daysOfWeek` setting for your business hours.  You said you did this because "I am only displaying one day at a time". However this makes no sense. The `daysOfWeek` setting specifies which days of the week the business hours apply to. It has no relationship to how many days your calendar's view is displaying simultaneously. FullCalendar still needs to know which calendar days to show business hours for, and which not to, so that when the user moves to the next day, it knows what to show.

If you don't include `daysOfWeek`, fullCalendar defaults to assuming Monday-Friday. (This is not documented, but the behaviour is observable by simply removing the setting from any existing businessHours definition.).

If we set up a simple demo using a businesshours where the same hours apply 7 days a week we can see that in all views, the business hours are shown correctly all days. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/OJyGGeJ .

Adding this one line of code is all you need to do to solve your problem:

```
  daysOfWeek: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ],
```